# Scrapy: Importing a package from the project that's not in the same directory

Tags: python, import, scrapy

I'm trying to import a package from my project which is not in the same directory as scrapy is in. The directory structure for my project is as follows:

```
Main
  __init__.py
  /XPaths
    __init.py
    XPaths.py
  /scrapper
    scrapy.cfg
    /scrapper
      __init.py
      settings.py
      items.py
      pipelines.py
      /spiders
        myspider.py
```

I'm trying to access `xpaths.py` from within `myspider.py`. Here are my attempts:

1) `from Main.XPaths.XPaths import XPathsHandler`

2) `from XPaths.XPaths import XPathsHandler`

3) `from ..Xpaths.XPaths import XPathsHandler`

These failed with the error:

```
ImportError: No module named .......
```

My last attempt was:

4) `from ...Xpaths.XPaths import XPathsHandler`

Which also failed with the error:

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package
```

What am I doing wrong? `XPaths` is independent from Scrapy, therefore the file structure has to stay that way.

//EDIT

After some further debugging following @alecxe comment, I tried adding the path to `main` inside the `sys.path`, and print it before importing xpaths. The weird thing is, the `scrapper` directory gets appended to the path when I run scrapy. Here's what I added:

```
'C:\\Users\\LaptOmer\\Code\\Python\\PythonBackend\\Main'
```

And here's what I get when I print `sys.path`:

```
'C:\\Users\\LaptOmer\\Code\\Python\\PythonBackend\\Main\\scrapper'
```

Why does scrapy append that to the path?

Comment: The first one should work if you append the `Main` package to `sys.path` - give it a try.

Comment: I tried it now but it didn't work - still getting the same errors.

Comment: Are you sure that is the same path? Scrapy adds his own when run: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1e2ee76df26cd86e8a6ed1b86879aacfce0a44a8/scrapy/utils/conf.py#L47

Answer (score 1):

I know its a little bit messy solution but only one I could find when I had same problem as you. Before including files from your project you need to manually append the system path to your top most package level, i.e:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../..'))
from XPaths.XPaths import XPathsHandler
...
```

From what I understand scrappy creates its own package - this is why you cannot import files from other directories. This also explains error:

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package
```

Comment: This is not pretty but was the only thing that worked, and i tried like 3 other suggestions from other posts before this one.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.

When I used:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../..'))
```

it appended `../..` to the last file path, which didn't work. I noticed my main file was the last item in the sys.path list. I took that last item and went to the module level to find my main file -- which contains a function called "extract_notes".

```
import scrapy
import sys
import os

mod_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.normpath(sys.path[-1]))
sys.path.insert(0,mod_path)

from pprint import pprint as p
from main import extract_notes
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar directory structure, with multiple scrapers (say directories `scraper1` and `scraper2`).

Since I found the `sys.path` changes as suggested by @ErdraugPl too brittle (see @ethanenglish's problems), especially since Scrapy itself is modifying the `sys.path`, I chose an OS solution instead of a Python solution: I created a symbolic link to directory `/XPaths` in both `scraper1` and `scraper2`. That way, I can still maintain a single `XPaths` module that I can use in both `scraper1` and `scraper2`, and can simply do `from XPaths.XPaths import XPathsHandler`