# In Python scrapy, With Multiple projects, How Do You Import A Class Method From One project Into Another project?

Tags: python, web-scraping, import, module, scrapy

## PROBLEM

I need to import a function/method located in scrapy project #1 into a spider in scrapy project # 2 *and use it in one of the spiders of project #2*.

### DIRECTORY STRUCTURE

For starters, here's my directory structure (assume these are all under one root directory):

```
/importables    # scrapy project #1 
    /importables
        /spiders
            title_collection.py    # take class functions defined from here

/alibaba        # scrapy project #2
    /alibaba
        /spiders
            alibabaPage.py         # use them here
```

## WHAT I WANT

As shown above, I am trying to get scrapy to:

1. Run `alibabaPage.py`
2. From `title_collection.py`, import a class method named `saveTitleInTitlesCollection` out of a class in that file named `TitleCollectionSpider`
3. I want to use `saveTitleInTitlesCollection` inside functions that are called in the `alibabaPage.py` spider.

## HOW IT'S GOING...

Here's what I've done so far at the top of `alibabaPage.py`:

1. `from importables.importables.spiders import saveTitleInTitlesCollection`

   - nope. Fails and the error says `builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importables'`
   - How can that be?  That answer I got from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43350207/scrapy-import-item-from-py-file-failes).
2. `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../..'))`
   Then, I did this...
   `from importables.importables.spiders import saveTitleInTitlesCollection`

   - nope, Fails and I get the same error as the first attempt. Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196458/scrapy-importing-a-package-from-the-project-thats-not-in-the-same-directory).
3. Re-reading the post in the link from answer #1, I realized the guy put the two files in the same directory, so, I tried doing that (making a copy of `title_collection.py` and putting it in like so:

```
/alibaba        # scrapy project #2
    /alibaba
        /spiders
            alibabaPage.py         # use them here
            title_collection.py    # added this
```

- Well, that appeared to work but didn't in the end.  This threw no errors...

```
from alibaba.spiders.title_collection import TitleCollectionSpiderAlibaba
```

Leading me to assume everything worked. I added a test function named `testForImport` and tried importing it, ended up getting error: `builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'alibaba.spiders.title_collection.testForImport'; 'alibaba.spiders.title_collection' is not a package`

- Unfortunately, this wasn't actually achieving the goal of importing the class method I want to use, named `saveTitleInTitlesCollection`.
- I have numerous scrapy projects and want to really just have one project of spiders **that I can just import into every other project with ease**.
- This is not that solution so, the quest for a true solution to importing a bunch of class methods from one scrapy project to many continues... *can this even be done I wonder...*
- WAIT, this actually didn't work after all because when  builtins.ModuleNotFoundError:
  No module named 'TitleCollectionSpiderAlibaba'

4. `from alibaba.spiders.title_collection import testForImport`

- nope. This failed too.

  But, this time it gave me slightly different error...

```
builtins.ImportError: 
cannot import name 'testForImport' from 'alibaba.spiders.title_collection' 
(C:\Users\User\\scrapy-webscrapers\alibaba\alibaba\spiders\title_collection.py)
```

## Consider this now solved!

Due to Umair's answer I was able to do this:

```
# typical scrapy spider imports...
import scrapy 
from ..items import AlibabaItem

# import this near the top of the page
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.abspath('../')))
from importables.importables.spiders.title_collection import TitleCollectionSpider


...

# then, in parse method I did this...
def parse(self, response):
    alibaba_item = AlibabaItem()
    title_collection_spider_obj = TitleCollectionSpider()
    title_collection_spider_obj.testForImportTitlesCollection()

# terminal showed this, proving it worked...
# "testForImport worked if you see this!"
```

Comment: The answer from Umair will help with resolve the import issues, but I still think you are going to have issues using an instance method from an un-instantiated class in another class.  You would be better off redefining the function as a standard function that takes a class instance as a parameter and putting it in it's own module and importing it into all other modules that need access to it

Comment: Initially this was a problem.  Until I tried instanciating the second class and, to my surprise, everything worked.  See my updated post above, showing I instanciate both classes.  It's my first time doing that (I didn't know you could do that in scrapy lol).  This implies I could import n number of classes and go bananas with the calling of any number of methods off those classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside `alibabaPage.py` you can do this to import class outside of your Scrapy project folder

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.abspath('../')))

from importables.importables.spiders.title_collection import TitleCollectionSpider
```

This will import class from `title_collection.py` into `alibabaPage.py`

Comment: Doing this threw no errors, so thank you for that.  However, inside the class `TitleCollectionSpider`, there is a test function I put there to prove this can be done named `testForImportTitlesCollection`  How do I run `testForImportTitlesCollection`?  I tried to use it in the `parse` method and it failed.  I did this... `testForImportTitlesCollection = TitleCollectionSpider.testForImportTitlesCollection` and then next line tried to do this `self.testForImportTitlesCollection()` but got error `builtins.AttributeError: 'AlibabapageSpider' object has no attribute 'testForImportTitlesCollection`

Comment: I was able to get it!  In `parse` I added this line first `title_collection_spider_obj = TitleCollectionSpider()`, then next line I added `title_collection_spider_obj.testForImportTitlesCollection()`.  When I checked the output I saw my print statement message (I put "testForImport worked if you see this!" in the print and it appeared in terminal when running alibabaPage.py) from scrapy project #1.  THANK YOU!